# How to call javascript function on click of a link?

Tags: javascript, php, html

When I click on Logout link, my logout.php file is called which logs me out.

```
<a href=logout.php>Logout</a>
```

How can I call following javascript function before calling the logout.php file on the click of the Logout link.

**Javascript function**

```
function callMeBeforeLogout()
{
    alert("Do you really want to logout?");
}
```

Comment: You have to add `onclick` event handler: `<a href=logout.php onclick="callMeBeforeLogout()">`

Comment: Add `onclick` event and for `href` you may want to use `javascript:;`.

Comment: @hindmost - your solution worked in the first attempt :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try like

```
<a href="javascript:;" onclick="callMeBeforeLogout();">Logout</a>
```

And in your function you have to write like

```
function callMeBeforeLogout()
{
    var cnfrm = confirm("Do you really want to logout?");
    if(cnfrm) {
        // here redirect to `logout.php`
        window.location.href = 'logout.php';
    }
}
```

Comment: Exactly how I would have suggested.. +1

Comment: @Fr0zenFyr ;-) but my ans was 3mins before your comment

Comment: I know,  hence I didn't repeat an answer.

Answer (score 5):

I prefer an unobtrusive approach

```
<a href="/logout" id="logout-link">logout</a>
```

Then add the script

```
<script>
  var logoutLink = document.getElementById("logout-link");

  logoutLink.addEventListener("click", function(event) {
    if (confirm("Do you really want to logout?")) return;
    event.preventDefault();
  });
</script>
```

If the user clicks "OK", they just follow the `href` provided in the original link (`/logout`)

If the user clicks "Cancel", the confirmation dialog will go away, and nothing happens.

If the user has JavaScript disabled, the link will work, just without confirmation dialog.

Comment: How did you use `logoutLink`?

Comment: refactor: `confirm('logout?') ? function(){return} : event.preventDefault();`

Comment: @bprayudha, I changed it a little bit.

Answer (score 3):

try add onclick event

```
<a href="javascript:void(0);" onclick="callMeBeforeLogout();">Logout</a>

function callMeBeforeLogout() {
  alert('hi i m here');
}
```

if you want to redirect use `window.location` or `window.location.href`